# Null pointer exception while adding JavaVO class in list

Tags: java

```
            FedespatchVO fedespatch = new FedespatchVO();
            List<FedespatchVO> listFedespatch = null;

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("I have something in me");
                fedespatch.setSerialNumber(rs.getString(1));
                fedespatch.setMachine(rs.getString(2));
                fedespatch.setHours(rs.getString(3));
                fedespatch.setTrigger(rs.getString(4));
                fedespatch.setNoticeTime(rs.getString(5));
                listFedespatch.add(fedespatch);
            }
```

> listFedespatch.add(fedespatch);

is throwing null pointer exception. I need to return back list of FedespatchVO class which is nothing but getter setter for attributes like serialNumber, Machine, NoticeTime etc.

Is my approach wrong? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you forgot to instantiate the `List` :

```
List<FedespatchVO> listFedespatch = null;
```

`listFedespatch` is a `null` reference and hence `listFedespatch.add()` will throw a [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Try instantiating it :

```
List<FedespatchVO> listFedespatch = new ArrayList<FedespatchVO>();
```

I have used an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) here , you can use any other implementations of [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 4):

> is throwing null pointer exception

Well yes, it would. Look how you're initializing it:

```
List<FedespatchVO> listFedespatch = null;
```

You're never setting it to a non-null reference, so when you call `add` on it, you'll *definitely* get an exception.

You probably want:

```
List<FedespatchVO> listFedespatch = new ArrayList<FedespatchVO>();
```

(You only need the `FedespatchVO` bit in the right hand side if you're using Java 6 or earlier; with Java 7 or later you can just have `new ArrayList<>();` and the type will be inferred.)

Answer (score 1):

At below line

```
List<FedespatchVO> listFedespatch = null;
```

listFedespatch reference contains null
and you are trying to acess it's setter methods on null reference in this situation it gives Null pointer exception

Solution is

```
 List<FedespatchVO> listFedespatch = new ArrayList<FedespatchVO>();
```