# Null key and values in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

`HashMap` allows one `null` key and multiple `null` values.

I want to know how does `HashMap` handle `null` key/values? I mean that how it is internally handled?

Comment: The JDK comes with the source code. Read it.

Comment: Everything has the source code. It does not mean that asking for shortcuts is bad idea for stackoverflow. I do not understand the purpose of stackoverflow if you cannot ask quetions like this here. Null obviouly does not have the .hashcode() method that hash map relies on. So, this is a perfect question. I do not understand why the questions that obviously suck, like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310177 are not downvoted but normal questions are still receiveing numerous downvotes. We have inverted morality and want to draw the stackoverflow into tubes.

Comment: This is a valid question and should have been answered properly, had it not been for its negative rating.

Answer (score 3):

*HashMap* defines two `private` methods to handle *`null`* keys:

- `getForNullKey()` which is invoked from the `get(K key)` method, if key is *`null`*, ~~and~~
- `putForNullKey(V value)`, which is invoked from the `put(K key, V value)` method if key is *`null`*.

You can find them in the source code.

And there is nothing as much to worry about handling null values. They are treated as normal values only.

Answer (score 2):

If you check [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.putForNullKey%28java.lang.Object%29)  It's mainining differenct methods to handle null

```
 Offloaded version of put for null keys
408 
409     private V More ...putForNullKey(V value) {
410         for (Entry<K,V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
411             if (e.key == null) {
412                 V oldValue = e.value;
413                 e.value = value;
414                 e.recordAccess(this);
415                 return oldValue;
416             }
417         }
418         modCount++;
419         addEntry(0, null, value, 0);
420         return null;
421     }



Offloaded version of get() to look up null keys. Null keys map to index 0. This null case is split out into separate methods for the sake of performance in the two most commonly used operations (get and put), but incorporated with conditionals in others.
334 
335     private V More ...getForNullKey() {
336         for (Entry<K,V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
337             if (e.key == null)
338                 return e.value;
339         }
340         return null;
341     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling Null key and value in HashMap

http://javaexplorer03.blogspot.in/2015/11/how-null-key-is-handled-in-hashmap.html

**Since equals() and hashCode() are used to store and retrieve values, how does it work in case of null key?**

Null key is handled specially in HashMap, there are two separate method for that **putForNullKey(V value) and getForNullKey()**. Later is offloaded version of get() to look up null keys. **Null keys always map to index 0.**

This null case is split out into separate methods for the sake of performance in the two most commonly used operations (get and put), but incorporated with conditionals in others.

In short, equals() and hashcode() method are not used in case of null keys in HashMap, here is how nulls are retrieved from HashMap.

```
private V getForNullKey() {
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        if (e.key == null)
            return e.value;
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Offloaded version of put for null keys
 */
private V putForNullKey(V value) {
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        if (e.key == null) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
    modCount++;
    addEntry(0, null, value, 0);
    return null;
}
```